# Remove Role Definitions From SPO Group - Power Automate - MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, power-automate, ms-flow

I'm trying to remove full control role definitions from Site Owner Group, because I have added another permission level through Power Automate/MS Flow.

From [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246239(v=office.15)) - Below is the syntax for POST Call

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/RoleAssignments(principalid)/RoleDefinitionBindings/remove(roleDefinition)
```

In Power Automate I tried like this

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSiteFromPA/_api/web/RoleAssignments(3)/RoleDefinitionBindings/remove(1073741829)
```

It says resource not found, I believe roledefinition is object not the roledefinition id but how can I send the object in Power Automate/Flow

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **DELETE** all roles from the group and then **ADD** back the desired role definition to the group.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: awesome! it worked